# <img src="my_image.GIF"> works but not .gifv

Tags: html

Any idea why this won't load?

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9OtS.gifv"> <!-- won't load -->
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/QvezdM)

But it works if you change gifv to gif.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9OtS.gifv = src

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9OtS.gif = gif src

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the `.gifv` is not an actual image. It is a url that is handled by imgur.com and shows the image in an html page (*hence the download button and imgur link*)

The `.gif` on the other hand, is a direct link to the image.